# Is there any way to do functional testing with googleMaps (android)?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, functional-testing, android-espresso

I'm currently doing functional testing with my Android application using [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso), its awesome. The issue is that I'd like to be able to test specific actions on the Map. As this whole app is centered around interactions with the map, is there any way to actually do it?

Things that would be great to do:

1. Click on map at certain latLng
2. Get the specific zoom level, etc.
3. Anything else that I can do with a map.

I was originally thinking I could call onView(withId(R.id.map))) to get an instance of the map, but that returns a view interactions which I don't believe helps. I'm willing to use other frameworks but if it can be done in espresso, that would be nice.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924564/using-espresso-to-unit-test-google-maps?answertab=active#tab-top