# Clicking an MarkerOptions using UIAutomator

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to make UIAutomator click the MarkerOptions on the Google Maps. [This solution does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924564/using-espresso-to-unit-test-google-maps/30519001#30519001)..

**build.gradle (App level)**

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
}
```

**TestClass**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ApplicationTest {

        UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        UiObject marker = device.findObject(new UiSelector().descriptionContains("title_of_marker. snippet_of_marker."));
        try {
            marker.click();
        } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

**MapsFragment.java**

```
private GoogleMap mMapView;

private void loadMapLocations() {

            mMapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(52.0988198,5.074657))
                    .title("title_of_marker")
                    .snippet("snippet_of_marker"));
}
```

[image]

**Output:**

```
W/System.err: android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObjectNotFoundException: UiSelector[CONTAINS_DESCRIPTION=title_of_marker. snippet_of_marker.]
W/System.err:     at android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObject.click(UiObject.java:412)
```

I've tried everything, but don't know how to proceed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a sample map and added a marker similar to yours.
Started [CulebraTester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/). Started a test recording. Clicked on the marker.

[image]

then I just added the `wait` (which will be autogenerated soon) to obtain this test.

```
@Test
public void culebraGeneratedTest() throws Exception {
    final BySelector bySelector = By.clazz(Pattern.compile(".*")).desc("title_of_marker. snippet_of_marker.").pkg("com.example.diego.mymapapplication");
    mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(bySelector), DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
    mDevice.findObject(bySelector).clickAndWait(Until.newWindow(), DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
}
```

Added the test class to the project.
Run the tests.
And **it works!**

It seems like a good opportunity to test **CulebraTester** code generation.

Comment: thnx I opted in for CulebraTester.

Comment: Tried this solution, followed this tutorial: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/android-ui-testing-androidviewclientculebra-ahmed-kasem but this doesn't work either.

Comment: the tutorial you mentioned is for python. The code I included in the answer is UiAutomator/Java. I tested the code and worked for me, what's not working for you? Did you change `"com.example.diego.mymapapplication"` to your pkg name?

Comment: Using your example method was enough, Culebra was not needed!

Comment: I thought it was clear that CulebraTester was only mentioned to indicate where or how I generated the code. CulebraTester is a powerful to help you generate this kind of code.

Answer (score 1):

I've used @Diego's example code and pasted this into my **ApplicationTest.java** and this works, so I don't need to use Culebra:

```
@Test
public void loginAndClickMarker() {

    UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    final BySelector bySelector = By.clazz(Pattern.compile(".*")).desc("title_of_marker. snippet_of_marker.").pkg("www.brandmkrs.com.damageapp");
    device.wait(Until.hasObject(bySelector), DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
    device.findObject(bySelector).clickAndWait(Until.newWindow(), DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: I thought it was clear that CulebraTester was only mentioned to indicate where or how I generated the code. CulebraTester is a powerful to help you generate this kind of code